# Command in test causing test to not to fully exit

Tags: mysql, macos, perl

I have a weird issue with the following perl test script on a mac with mysql and apache installed:

```
# stop all servers
`mysql.server stop 2>&1`;
`apachectl -k graceful-stop 2>&1`;

is apache_is_running(), 0, 'determines if apache is not running';
`apachectl -k start 2>&1`;

is apache_is_running(), 1, 'determines apache is running';
is mysql_is_running(), 0, 'determines mysql is not running';

system "mysql.server start 2>&1";

is mysql_is_running(), 1, 'determines mysql is running';
print "hi\n";
exit;
```

When I run the test with `prove -l --verbose`, I get the following output:

```
1..4
# Running my tests
ok 1 - determines if apache is not running
ok 2 - determines apache is running
ok 3 - determines mysql is not running
Starting MySQL
. SUCCESS!
ok 4 - determines mysql is running
hi
```

Then the test just hangs and never fully exits. It's something about the last command that causes this: `system "mysql.server start 2>&1";` I've tried with backticks instead of `system` but that didn't help. If I take out this last command, it exits fine as expected.

Comment: Some packages need something on the standard input. Try adding `< /dev/null` to set the standard input to nothing.

Comment: Like this? `system "mysql.server start 2>&1 < /dev/null";` I tried it, no effect.

Comment: I usually set the standard input before the standard output and error. I don't recall if it makes any difference. Something like: `system "mysql.server start  < /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: I tried `system "mysql.server start  < /dev/null  2>&1"` and a few other iterations, no luck, though.

Comment: If you are running linux/unix, you'll need to enclose it in `nohup` and `&` to be truly running in the background. If this is your case you could try: `system "nohup mysql.server start 2>&1  </dev/null >log.file &"`.

Comment: I got it. I had to change from `< /dev/null` to `> /dev/null`. No idea why. Redirection commands are a weak spot for me.

Comment: So command that works is: `system "mysql.server start >/dev/null 2>&1";`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the standard output was not set. You may consider the `nohup` / `&`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is what fixed it, but I'm still not clear why, however:

```
`mysql.server start >/dev/null 2>&1`;
```